# performing function with classes of similar type C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, iterator, polymorphism

I want to implement a representation of matrices.
for that I have two types of matrices - regular and sparse, which differ in their
implementation - one holds a vector, and the second a map of indices and value,
both inherit from Matrix class.

I want to implement the + operator, which operates on Matrix and receives another Matrix.
but when I implement the + operator, I might receive as parameter sparse/regular matrix.

is there any way to receive a matrix, which I don't know what type of the 2 it is,
and perform the + operator?
meaning, if in class SparseMatrix I receive sparse/regular matrix, how can I implement the operator such that no matter which of the two types I get, it will work?

```
Matrix & operator+ (Matrix other)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Pass the Matrix by reference and use polymorphism (a common Matrix base class).

Answer (score 0):

I would probably implement two versions of `operator+`, and let them call a helper template method:

```
template <typename ITER>
Matrix add (ITER other_it) {
    //...
}

Matrix operator+ (RegularMatrix other)
{
    return add(other.begin());
}

Matrix operator+ (SparseMatrix other)
{
    return add(other.begin());
}
```

You could make `operator+` a template, but this way makes sure you only allow those `Matrix` types.

As was pointed out to me, you should not return a reference from `+`, as the result needs to be point to an instance that exists after the operation returns.

Comment: I think that should be noted that returning a reference from a binary operator is not a good idea. In fact that has UB in this case, since you are returning a reference to a local variable (Note you passed the matrix by value)

Comment: About passing by value, I like the good old `const&`, but I don't wanna start again the *"Wants speed? Pass by value!"* debate again here.

Comment: @Manu343726: Good point about returning reference. Thanks. As for passing in a reference vs. copy, the performance depends on how well the compiler implements copy elision.

Answer (score 0):

We can use polymorphism to create different implementations of a Matrix. Through the common interface of `Matrix`, each implementation can interact.

```
   class Matrix
   {
      class iterator { ... }

      friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix &lhs, const Matrix &rhs)
      {
         // iterate, add, and return new matrix
      }
   };

   class SpareMatrix : public Matrix
   {
      iterator begin() { ... }
   };
```

Comment: thanks, but then how can I perform addition with two different matrix types? if one contains a map and the second a vector, I can't generalize the addition between the two of them

Comment: I changed my mind a bit. The Matrix base class will have the overloaded addition operator and each subclass must uniquely implement the iterator to work with the different implementation of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Matrix
{
public:
    virtual ~Matrix() {}

    virtual Matrix& operator+(Matrix& other) = 0;
};

class MatrixSparse : public Matrix
{
public:
    virtual ~MatrixSparse() {}
    virtual Matrix& operator+(Matrix& other)
    {
        MatrixSparse* sparse = dynamic_cast<MatrixSparse*>(&other);
        // TODO
    }
};

class MatrixRegular : public Matrix
{
public:
    virtual ~MatrixRegular() {}
    virtual Matrix& operator+(Matrix& other)
    {
        MatrixRegular* regular = dynamic_cast<MatrixRegular*>(&other);
        // TODO
    }
};
```

Also, here is [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867430/what-is-the-proper-way-to-overload-operators-in-abstract-base-classes) dealing with the problem of overloading operators from abstract classes.