# A function to return different derived-type object/reference not a pointer

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

How to create a function returning a derived-**object/reference**?
I have this code that uses the covariance method. However, I prefer the return to be an object, not a pointer.

What I have and it's working fine.

```
class Base {    
    protected:
        Base(){};
    public:
        virtual ~Base(){};
        virtual void print() = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base 
{
    public:
        Derived1() : Base() {};
        ~Derived1() {};
        void print() override { std::cout << "Derived1" << std::endl;}
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
    public:
        Derived2() : Base() {};
        ~Derived2() {};
        void print() override { std::cout << "Derived2" << std::endl;}
};


std::unique_ptr<Base> getDerived(int t)
{
    if (t == 2)
        return std::make_unique<Derived2>();
    // default
    return std::make_unique<Derived1>();
}

int main()
{
    auto d1_p = getDerived(1);
    auto d2_p = getDerived(2);
    d1_p->print(); // "Derived1"
    d2_p->print(); // "Derived2"
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works fine and prints out "Derived1" and "Derived2" correctly.

However, I would like to get an object than a pointer. Ideally, this should work.

```
int main()
{
    auto d1_p = getDerived(1);
    auto d2_p = getDerived(2);
    d1_p.print(); // "Derived1"  
    d2_p.print(); // "Derived2"
    return 0
}
```

Are there any workaround?

Comment: No, this is impossible, see linked duplicate. *Why* do you need this?

Comment: The real problem that I'm working on needs a function that conditionally returns a specific derived-type at runtime. And there are multiple derived-type to be returned based on multiple conditions inside that function.

Comment: That can be done using a `std::unqiue_ptr` as you demonstrate in your example. I still don't see why you need the object itself, directly? Note that you can in principle use polymorphism via references instead of pointers, but references do not offer the lifetime management that `std::unique_ptr` does.

Comment: I tried to reframe the problem here. But my real problem is I need an operator overload.

(Derived1 or Derived 2)  operator+ (const Base& a, const Base& b)
{
    // some runtime operations 
    if (condition1 == true)
        return Derived1;
    
    return Derived2;
}
So I couldn't create two function signatures with different return types. Since it must compile at runtime.

Comment: For the next time, please ask directly about your specific use case. That makes it easier to give helpful answers. With regards to what you mention now in your comment: You cannot return polymorphically from `+` and have it have usual (non-pointer) syntax. You could instead write a non-polymorphic wrapper class holding a polymorphic pointer to implement the usual `+` syntax, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10187258/11941443) (although you should use `std::unique_ptr` instead of `new`). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867430).

Comment: Thanks a lot, walnut. I'll keep that in mind. Thought reframing is better but it seems like a bad idea.